# Will commercialisation and widespread use of A.I in security and surveillance and other household products threaten free will or endanger privacy?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, autonomous-vehicles, facial-recognition

Everything from facial recognition to the google home is coming equiped with A.I and it is being widely used , If autonomously connected to the internet , will A.I pose a threat to privacy or will it endanger free will if used for surveillance with facial recognition , like in the movie 'Minority Report'

Comment: Welcome to ai.se...It is highly unclear what you are asking..There have been a few questions of this type in this SE, but all of them has been given a specific scenario..I suggest you go through the questions and add more details to your question

Comment: How much is your free will affected by police looking at your face to see if you're a wanted criminal?

Comment: Definitely needs an edit, but a solid question.  A. Free will has not been verified, so you should avoid this term. I suspect what you might be indicating is stronger influence over human decisions by sophisticated algorithms.  B. Privacy, this is an issue already, regardless of AI.  AI can certainly be used to exacerbate the problem.  *Again, legit question, just needs to be reformulated.*

Comment: somebody edit/rephrase this : )

Comment: @DenizC this is not that , this is where A.I takes decisions based on facts and previous true assumptions